# Strange implicit resolution behaviour with type classes and package objects

Tags: scala

I'm trying to provide different sets of implementations for a list of type classes, where importing different package objects would give the end user a different version of a `TypeClass` implementation into scope, with the swap being completely invisible.

```
trait TypeClass[T] {
  def name: String
}


trait DefaultTypeClasses {
  implicit val String: TypeClass[String]
  implicit val Int: TypeClass[Int]
}

trait FirstImplementor extends DefaultTypeClasses {
  implicit object String extends TypeClass[String] {
    def name = "test"
  }

  implicit object Int extends TypeClass[Int] {
    def name = "int"
  }
}

object FirstImplementor extends FirstImplementor


object Test {

  import FirstImplementor._

  def doSomething[T : TypeClass](value: T): Unit = {
    println(implicitly[TypeClass[T]].name)
  }

  doSomething("test")

}
```

The above works as expected, but if do:

```
trait DefaultDefinitions extends DefaultTypeClasses {
}
package object something extends DefaultDefinitions with FirstImplementor {}
```

And then I import the same `package object` into the scope of the `Test` object, like this:

```
import com.blabla.something._ // should bring all type class definitions from FirstImplementor into scope.

object Test {

  def doSomething[T : TypeClass](value: T): Unit = {
    println(implicitly[TypeClass[T]].name)
  }

  doSomething("test")// Cannot find implicit value for TypeClass[String]
  doSomething[String]("test")(String) // if passed explicitly it compiles as expected, no more imports necessary.
}
```

For whatever reason, the materialised type class is available in explicit scope by name, but not in implicit scope. Sounds like my knowledge of the SLS is experiencing a gap, could anyone please clarify?

Comment: Test is also in package something? If so import something._ is not required and it compiles for me successfully

Comment: after I moved test to other package I got the same problem

Comment: import something.String solves the problem

Comment: Hi @EugeneZhulenev, but it would lead to really ugly syntax and fruitless imports.

Comment: agree, for me it looks like a bug in scalac

Comment: What also solves the problem is removing the ```DefaultTypeClasses``` subclassing and just implementing things. This doesn't confine implementors to provide all implementations but it works if they do it independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But if you create Implicits object in package, it works fine. However I have no idea if original error is a bug in scalac or correct behavior

```
package object something  {
  object Implicits extends DefaultDefinitions with FirstImplementor
}

import something.Implicits._
```

Comment: It seems more like a limitation concerning package objects. But the proposed approach, independent of that bug or limitation, is nice and you can see it all over the place (in many Scala libraries) for bringing implicit conversions to the context.